# Is there an alternative proof of the abel-ruffini theorem?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I'm just asking if there's a proof of the insolvability of the general quintic avoiding the uses of Galois correspondence and Galois extension.

Comment: I think Abel's original proof did not use Galois groups but I'm not sure and I don't know where to find it.

Comment: This article details Abel's original proof: http://www.math.caltech.edu/~jimlb/abel.pdf

Comment: I've never even read his proof before. Is Abel proof worth-understand and does it give any good mathematical insight?

Comment: Regardless of the technique involved, the main distinction between the Abel-Ruffini theorem and the work of Galois on solvability of polynomial equations is that Abel-Ruffini is only about polynomials with "generic" (algebraically independent) coefficients while Galois lets us say things about specific polynomials with numerical coefficients. That is, when Abel-Ruffini show there is no quintic formula, it does not actually prove that a particular numerical quintic (with rational coefficients, say) has no radical formula for its roots. Abel-Ruffini can't be applied to $x^5-x-1$ but Galois can.

Comment: I have described such a proof in my blog posts [here](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/12/abel-and-the-insolvability-of-the-quintic-part-1.html?m=0).

Comment: @KCd: rightly put! As per my understanding, Galois theory is not so much about finding roots but rather understanding the structure of splitting field. And then the issue of getting roots via radicals is just one aspect of that structure which may or may not be possessed by some polynomial.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh the viewpoint of Galois theory as being about splitting fields is due to Artin, almost 100 years after Galois.

Comment: @KCd: yes Artin changed the way people looked at work of Galois in a very fundamental way. Galois was dealing with functions of the roots which remain invariant under the permutations of the roots and Artin just called the set of these functions as the splitting field and the permutations got replaced by automorphisms which leave the field of coefficients fixed. I am still a novice in this area and find the transition a bit more abstract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~smahanta/Teaching/Spring10/Stillwell.pdf) may be to your liking.  It still uses the concept of Galois groups (it's hard to see how one could avoid that), but does not use the Galois correspondence.

Answer (score 2):

Here I have some related references.

[Lerner, L.: Galois theory without abstract algebra. 2011](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4593)

[Goldmakher, L.: Arnold's elementary proof of the insolvability of the quintic. 2018](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/ARNOLD%E2%80%99S-ELEMENTARY-PROOF-OF-THE-INSOLVABILITY-OF/30dd0940e39576fc75bf0b60c90ef8126b855c00)

[Zoladek, H.: The topological proof of Abel-Ruffini theorem. Topological Methods in Nonlinear Analysis 16 (2000) 253-265](https://apcz.umk.pl/czasopisma/index.php/TMNA/article/view/TMNA.2000.040)

[Ramond, P.: Abel-Ruffini’s theorem: Complex but not complicated !. 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.05162)

[Yan Pan, Yuzhen Chen: A new proof of Abel-Ruffini theorem. 2020](https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/1912.07489/)

[Skopenkov: A short elementary proof of the insolvability of the equation of degree 5. 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.03317)